# Difference between two different ways of Base64 conversions in Java

Tags: java, base64, urlencode

I am trying to figure out what is difference between these two ways of Base64 conversions:

First:

```
String base64EncodedMsg = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(messageInBytes);
```

and

Second:

```
String base64EncodedMsg = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(messageInBytes));
```

Where `messageInBytes` is of type `byte[]`

For a certain value of `messageInBytes`, values of `base64EncodedMsg` slightly differ.

With first call I get it as:

```
1HuW7rb7_l7NC7LwR7cRV2K-rlr7SnGdoEuGntxDKX8=
```

And with second call I get it as:

```
1HuW7rb7/l7NC7LwR7cRV2K+rlr7SnGdoEuGntxDKX8=
```

Can someone please explain? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two methods of `Base64` instance are just returning `Encoder` with different policy of RFC4648 base64 conversion standard.

Just compare:

```
public static Encoder getEncoder() {
     return Encoder.RFC4648;
}
```

and:

```
public static Encoder getUrlEncoder() {
     return Encoder.RFC4648_URLSAFE;
}
```

Read more here:

- [RFC4648 Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5)

and compare it's alphabet with the alphabet in [previous Base64 converseion section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The standard base-64 alphabet contains the characters `+` and `/`, which have special meaning in a URL.  To deal with this, there's a "URL friendly" variant of base-64, which doesn't use these characters - it uses `-` and `_` instead.  This saves things from getting scrambled if you use a base-64 string in a URL.

Your two snippets of code show conversion to "URL friendly base-64" and standard base-64 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Base64 alphabets of "digits." Both Base64 use 26 capital letters + 26 small letters + 10 digits = 62 digits. The normal Base64 adds `+` and `/`. The URL safe Base64 uses the neutral `-` and `_`.

As a Base64 digit represents 6 bits, 4 digits represent 3 bytes.
As padding at the end with `=`s is done.

```
base64EncodedMsg = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(messageInBytes));
```

gives the normal Base64, but contains a non-portable error.
The `new String(bytes)` uses the platform encoding and hence is not portable. As long as the platform encoding is a superset of ASCII it works, but encodings like wide characters (UTF-16) or EBCDIC would corrupt the message.

Correct is `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` or simply:

```
base64EncodedMsg = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(messageInBytes);
```